# c# (more specifically xna) how can i request a xml file via http? Doesnt need to support xbox

Tags: c#, xml, http, xna, request

So im working on a game in XNA and i need it to get a server list off our site.

so i just need to do a http request to http://play.feedthezombie.com/?want=servers&enc=xml
and get the contest as either a string or xml object.

any clues?

Answer (score 3):

Use [XmlDocument.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/875kz807.aspx) method. It can load XML from an URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can call any .NET framework classes you like on Windows, including ones that do network access and XML handling. On Xbox you are limited to what XNA provides to you which is a subset of the .NET framework and the only network access is through the Xbox Live APIs.